# Is there any way to avoid a Realm schema migration (i.e. just start from scratch)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm just learning Realm and my schema is evolving.  I changed some of my objects from "Object" to "EmbeddedObject" now my iOS app is crashing during Realm migration.  I'm really not interested in migrating anything - I'd like to start from scratch.    I tried "deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded" as well as deleting the actual Realm file, but it still crashes in the same place.  Is there any way to configure Realm to just blow away all of the previous work and start over again?

Here is my code:

```
var config = Realm.Configuration(deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true)
        let realmURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MyRealm")
        config.fileURL = realmURL
        let theRealm = try! Realm()   // <<-- crashes here
```

Comment: Figured it out... I need to set the default realm configuration.   Adding this line before "try! Realm()" resolves the issue:           Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Just needed to set the defaultConfiguration prior to "try! Realm()"

```
    var config = Realm.Configuration(deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true)
    let realmURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MyRealm")
    config.fileURL = realmURL
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    let theRealm = try! Realm()
```